# How do I make an image fall from the sky

Tags: python, pygame

I currently have the image I want to use and understand you need to use gravity and speed in the y direction but was wondering how to put it all together preferably in a class.

If possible I'm also wondering how to make it so there is a random chance of the image appearing and falling.

Comment: makes its y coords increase every loop. But You have to provide Your efforts on this issue a.k.a. Your code/what You have already tried [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). oh and yes it is very much possible

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how that might look like:

```py
import pygame
import random


pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((900, 600))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


class FallingImage:
    def __init__(self, file, x, y, width, height):
        self.file = file
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(self.file).convert_alpha(), (self.width, self.height))

    def draw(self):
        screen.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))


falling_img = FallingImage('your_image.png', 300, -100, 50, 100)

run = True
while run:

    clock.tick(60)

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

    falling_img.draw()
    falling_img.y += 25
    if falling_img.y > 600:
        falling_img.y = -150
        falling_img.x = random.randint(0, 900)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: @BuddyBob if that was their homework then only partially, this is just an example so the implementations could be different, however if it wasn't a homework then I haven't done their homework since they didn't have that, also kinda late to ask such kinda unrelated question, don't you think? this was like two months ago

Comment: just askin bud.